# Is the congruence $x^2\equiv n\;(mod\,m) $ has a solution?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

It is possible that $ (\frac{n}{m})=1$ while the congruence $x^2\equiv n\;(mod\,m) $ has a solution:

Is this true for every prime dividing n  i am confusing about this problem can any one help me

Comment: **Legendre Symbol Definition:** If $n\in\mathbb Z$, $p$ is prime, then 

$$\left(\frac{n}{p}\right)=\begin{cases}1&& \text{if }x^2\equiv n\pmod{p}\text{ has a solution, } p\nmid n\\-1&& \text{if }x^2\equiv n\pmod{p}\text{ does not have a solution}\\0&& \text{if } p\mid n\end{cases}$$

**Jacobi Symbol Definition:** If $n,m\in\mathbb Z$ and $m=p_1^{\alpha_1}p_2^{\alpha_2}\cdots p_k^{\alpha_k}$ is the unique prime factorization of $m$, then

$$\left(\frac{n}{m}\right)=\left(\frac{n}{p_1}\right)^{\alpha_1} \left(\frac{n}{p_2}\right)^{\alpha_2}\cdots \left(\frac{n}{p_k}\right)^{\alpha_k}$$

Comment: This Jacobi Symbol definition does not tell you anything about the congruence $x^2\equiv n\pmod{m}$.

Answer (score 2):

This is a confusion about the Jacobi vs Legendre symbols.

When $m$ is prime and $n$ is coprime to $m$, $\left( \frac{n}{m} \right) = 1$ (the Legendre symbol) means, by definition, precisely that $x^2 \equiv n \pmod{m}$ has a solution.

But when $m$ is composite, we use instead the definition of the Jacobi symbol, that $$\left( \frac{n}{p_1 p_2} \right) = \left( \frac{n}{p_1} \right) \left( \frac{n}{p_2} \right)$$

Therefore, for instance, $$\left( \frac{2}{15} \right) = 1$$
even though $2$ is not square mod $15$.

The converse is true: if $n$ is square mod $m$ (and the two are coprime), then $$\left( \frac{n}{m} \right) = 1$$
whether or not $m$ is prime.

Comment: @ patrick ...thanks how is true for prime

Comment: @Psuresh By definition.

Comment: ...i am confusing can you explain me briefly..acording you this si true for prime...aand it si not true for compiste number right

Comment: What specifically is confusing? I don't see how to explain any further than I already have in my answer.